# Python "yield" keyword to calculate

Tags: python, generator, yield

A bar shop has a ten-day promotion. During this period, the price of an beer drops 10 percent each day. For example, a beer that costs 10$ on the first day costs $9 on the second day and $8.1 on the third day.

I want to write a python function that uses `yield` keyword to calculate beer price each day.

For instance if we give input 10, 
My expected output is:

```
Price is discounted to : 9

Price is discounted to : 8.1
```

..etc

```
class DiscountCalc:
    def get_item_price(self):
        return input('Input a starting price (0 to quit): ')


    def discount(self, current_price, days):
        yield (current_price - (current_price*10)//100)



    def run(self):
        initial = self.get_item_price()
        for price in self.discount(initial, 10):
            print "Price is discounted to : " + str(price)

DiscountCalc().run()
```

Comment: So, what *exactly* is your question? As an side, this class seems pretty... unnecessary. There isn't any internal state.

Comment: If I add the "yield (current_price - (current_price*10)//100)" to my discount class, I am getting input as only  "Price is discounted to : 9" which is onlay first day, but I want to get result for other days too.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47681818/edit) your question with the code you are using that is not working. I cannot tell what *exactly* you mean by "If I add the "yield (current_price - (current_price*10)//100)" to my discount class". *Add it where*?

Comment: @Alice Please put your attempt with the `yield` statement in the question with the description of what it's doing and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I did, as you see I add my yield statement to my discount class, it is only giving output as only for one day, I want to get output for other days too, Probably I will use loop but, how?

Comment: from .so import "homework"
homework.getAnswer()

Answer (score 2):

it's due to the cycle, this should fix it:

```
def discount(self, current_price, days):
    for day in range(days):
        yield current_price
        current_price = current_price * 0.9


def run(self):
    initial = self.get_item_price()
    for price in self.discount(initial, 10):
        print(price)
```